# How to pull data from a HTML element in a website with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, http, meteor

I want to pull data from this website: http://neconome.com/S0K01.html?bkn_cd=110248

More specifically I would like to pull the information inside this html  element:

```
<td colspan="2">呼出番号：33番　<br>待ち人数：2人</td>
```

And then store it as a variable.

Comment: is there any identifier for this `td`

Comment: @user2181397 no there isn't. There's only the colspan value.

Comment: First write the scraper to get the html of that page, then show us your code where you try to extract the value of this element, then it will be easier to help you. You should be able to select the element with `$('td[colspan=2]')`